# PDF Report from Kibana Application size changed when send via e-mail

Tags: python, kibana

I am trying via python script to generate from Kibana Dashboard a PDF report and the same one to sent via email. The generated report in kibana/elasticsearch is 135KB and I am able to open, but when I receive the same report on email it has only 95KB. Below you can find the python Script. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong with encoding. If you can provide any inputs I would really appreciate.

```
import smtplib
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def fetch_kibana_data():

    # Set up Kibana API endpoint and headers
    kibana_url = 'Kibana Url'
    search_endpoint = f'{kibana_url}/api/reporting/generate/dashboard URI'
    headers = {'kbn-xsrf': 'true'}

    username = 'kibana username'
    password = 'kibana passw'

    if not username or not password:
        raise Exception("Kibana credentials not found in environment variables.")

    response = requests.post(search_endpoint, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch data from Kibana: {response.text}")

    pdf_content = pdf_response.content

def send_email(data, pdf_content):
    from_email = 'from email'
    to_email = 'to email'
    subject = 'Weekly Kibana Report'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    # Add JSON data as text in the email body
    body = str(data)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

   # Attach the PDF report to the email
    pdf_attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    pdf_attachment.set_payload(pdf_content)
    encoders.encode_base64(pdf_attachment)
    pdf_attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename=report.pdf')
    msg.attach(pdf_attachment)

    # Send the email
    smtp_server = 'mail.your-server.de'
    smtp_port = 587
    smtp_username = 'username'
    smtp_password = 'ppassw'
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

def main():
    report_data = fetch_kibana_data()

    if 'path' in report_data:
        download_path = report_data['path']
        # dd the base URL to the relative download path
        base_url = 'Kibana base URL'
        full_download_url = f'{base_url}{download_path}'

        pdf_response = requests.get(full_download_url, verify=False)
        if pdf_response.status_code == 200:
            pdf_content = pdf_response.content
            send_email(report_data, pdf_content)
        else:
             print(f"Failed to fetch PDF: {pdf_response.text}")
    else:
        print("No 'path' found in the report data.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried also to change the MIMEBase:

```
pdf_attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
```

to

```
pdf_attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'pdf')
```

but still getting the same result via email. File is stil 95KB.